# Sony Smartwatch 2 develop a clock

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I've just bought a Sony Smartwatch 2 and I'm working with the samples, but I'm trying something that I don't know how to do it and I don't find an example too.

I know how to develop a clock and a widget so they appear in the watch faces settings but they can not be in the same cell in the grid. I mean, if I develop an analog clock of 5x5 cells then I can not add any widget. And if I develop an analog clock of 4x4 cells, then I can add widgets bu only if they occupy the other 9 cells.

But I can see that some watch faces in Google play or even the predefined watch faces in the Smartwatch are analog clocks occuping the 5x5 grid and with some widget inside them, as the date. 
Now my question is, how could I do this? How could I develop an 5x5 analog clock and add some widgets inside them?

I've tried to make a 3x3 or 4x4 clock and modifying the com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout background but it seems it has no effect.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Rubén.

Comment: You have a smart **watch** and you're developing a clock application for it. Does anyone else find this a little strange? :-)

Comment: Then I haven't explained myself well. With Sony Smartwatch you can develop your own "clocks", this is the style and look&feel of the clock, they call them faces. You can show analog or digital displays, dates, number of notifications, in the position you want, etc...This is what I'm trying to develop, my own style face. Anyway, just seconds after I click on the post question button I've seen that you can change the background of the face with other field of the XML layout, so I'm trying this.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to change the ImageView source in the XML layout but it seems that has not effect again :-S. I will keep investigating, meanwhile any clue of how to do this?

Comment: Well I finally found that my changes were being applied but not in the preview mode. Anyway, my changes only affect to the grid occupied by the clock so I have the same problem, I can not add any widget inside the clock. How could I change the background of a watch face or how could I add widgets inside a clock?

Comment: Well I finally found it how to do it. It was very simple :-S. In the XML where you define the clock face you can include any layout you want to show just with <include layout="@layout/my_layout_inside_a_clock" />